# My function to create a number divisible to 30 broke in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, integer, division

Note: I'm not good at my English, and edits is greatly accepted

I have a function that create the greatest number that is divisible by 30 from the user's input in c++. If can't create then return -1 .

Some sample:

```
input :
2 // how many input numbers
3 0 // input
output:
30

input:
2
3 1
output :
-1

input:
11
4 9 6 0 6 9 4 9 0 6 3
output:
999666300
```

My apporach is to check if the number is divisible by 3 and 10, because `gcd(3, 10) = 1` thus if a number is divisible by 3 and 10 it will divisible by 30.

I first create a function with a `string` type.

Numbers is lagre, so I think it's best to store all the numbers in a `vector<int>`, then sorted it form biggest to smallest, because I need to crete the biggest number.

```
string create30div (vector<int> vecNum)
{
    sort(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), greater<int>());
}
```

Then I first checked if the array has the number 0, because a number divisible by 10 when it has a 0 in the end. I use the find function to check if the vector has a 0 on it, if not then return -1 immedialey.

```
string create30div (vector<int> vecNum)
{
    sort(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), greater<int>());
    if (find(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) == vecNum.end())
    {
        return "-1";
    }
}
```

Else, if the vector has a 0, then I add the total of all the array and first check if the total is divisible by 0, if yes then just put all the number of the vector to a string and return it.

```
string create30div (vector<int> vecNum)
{
    sort(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), greater<int>());
    if (find(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) == vecNum.end())
    {
        return "-1";
    }
    else
    {
        if (accumulate(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) % 3 == 0)
        {
            goto sum;
        }
    }
sum:
    string sum {};
    for (auto i : vecNum)
    {
        sum += to_string(i);
    }
    return sum;

}
```

NOTE: I know it's not good when use `goto` in c++, but I really don't want to write sum all over agian. Do you guys have a better solution than me?

Back to the problem, if the number isn't divisible by 3, there is two case:
divide by 3 has the remainder of 1 or remainder of 2

If divide by 3 has the remainder of 1, I first checked the `vector` in reverse order to see if there are any number that divide by 3 has the remainder of 1, if yes then delete the number and return sum

```
string create30div (vector<int> vecNum)
{
    sort(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), greater<int>());
    if (find(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) == vecNum.end())
    {
        return "-1";
    }
    else
    {
        if (accumulate(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) % 3 == 0)
        {
            goto sum;
        }
        else if (accumulate(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) % 3 == 1)
        {
            bool isNumMod1Exist{false};
            for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
            {
                if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 1)
                {
                    vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);
                    isNumMod1Exist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isNumMod1Exist)
            {
                goto sum;
            }
     }
sum:
    string sum {};
    for (auto i : vecNum)
    {
        sum += to_string(i);
    }
    return sum;

}
```

If there aren't, I then check if there are two numbers that divide by 3 has the remainder of 2, if yes then delete all of it, if not then return -1.

```
string create30div (vector<int> vecNum)
{
    sort(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), greater<int>());
    if (find(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) == vecNum.end())
    {
        return "-1";
    }
    else
    {
        if (accumulate(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) % 3 == 0)
        {
            goto sum;
        }
        else if (accumulate(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) % 3 == 1)
        {
            bool isNumMod1Exist{false};
            for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
            {
                if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 1)
                {
                    vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);
                    isNumMod1Exist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isNumMod1Exist)
            {
                goto sum;
            }
            else
            {
                int counter{0};
                for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 2)
                    {
                        vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);
                        counter++;
                        i--;
                        if (counter >= 2)
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (counter >= 2)
                {
                    goto sum;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "-1";
                }

            }
        }
sum:
    string sum {};
    for (auto i : vecNum)
    {
        sum += to_string(i);
    }
    return sum;

}
```

The same if the whole number divide by 3 has the remainder of 2.

```
string create30div (vector<int> vecNum)
{
    sort(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), greater<int>());
    if (find(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) == vecNum.end())
    {
        return "-1";
    }
    else
    {
        if (accumulate(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) % 3 == 0)
        {
            goto sum;
        }
        else if (accumulate(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) % 3 == 1)
        {
            bool isNumMod1Exist{false};
            for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
            {
                if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 1)
                {
                    vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);
                    isNumMod1Exist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isNumMod1Exist)
            {
                goto sum;
            }
            else
            {
                int counter{0};
                for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 2)
                    {
                        vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);
                        counter++;
                        i--;
                        if (counter >= 2)
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (counter >= 2)
                {
                    goto sum;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "-1";
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            bool isNumMod2Exist{false};
            for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
            {
                if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 2)
                {
                        vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);
                        isNumMod2Exist = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (isNumMod2Exist)
            {
                goto sum;
            }
            else
            {
                int counter{0};
                for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 1)
                    {
                        vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);
                        counter++;
                        i--;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (counter >= 2)
                {
                    goto sum;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "-1";
                }

            }



        }

    }
sum:
    string sum {};
    for (auto i : vecNum)
    {
        sum += to_string(i);
    }
    return sum;

}
```

And the driver code.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> vecNum;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int inputVec;
        cin >> inputVec;
        vecNum.push_back(inputVec);
    }
    cout << create30div(vecNum);
}
```

But I have a problem that this program produce unexpected relsut. For example:

```
input:
11
4 9 6 0 6 9 4 9 0 6 3
It outputs:
-1
```

Why?

p/s: I know this post is much longer than it should be, but I just want to let you know what I'm thinking while doing this program.

full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string create30div (vector<int> vecNum)
{
    sort(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), greater<int>());
    if (find(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) == vecNum.end())
    {
        return "-1";
    }
    else
    {
        if (accumulate(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) % 3 == 0)
        {
            goto sum;
        }
        else if (accumulate(vecNum.begin(), vecNum.end(), 0) % 3 == 1)
        {
            bool isNumMod1Exist{false};
            for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
            {
                if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 1)
                {
                    vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);
                    isNumMod1Exist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isNumMod1Exist)
            {
                goto sum;
            }
            else
            {
                int counter{0};
                for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 2)
                    {
                        vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);
                        counter++;
                        i--;
                        if (counter >= 2)
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (counter >= 2)
                {
                    goto sum;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "-1";
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            bool isNumMod2Exist{false};
            for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
            {
                if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 2)
                {
                        vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);
                        isNumMod2Exist = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (isNumMod2Exist)
            {
                goto sum;
            }
            else
            {
                int counter{0};
                for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 1)
                    {
                        vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);
                        counter++;
                        i--;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (counter >= 2)
                {
                    goto sum;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "-1";
                }

            }



        }

    }
sum:
    string sum {};
    for (auto i : vecNum)
    {
        sum += to_string(i);
    }
    return sum;

}



int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> vecNum;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int inputVec;
        cin >> inputVec;
        vecNum.push_back(inputVec);
    }
    cout << create30div(vecNum);
}
```

Comment: How to get rid of the `goto` make a function. Put the loops you are `goto`ing out of into the function. Replace the `goto` with a `return`.

Comment: English is fine. The problem is the question goes on and on. I gave up and went looking for something else to do before it got to the point.

Comment: @user4581301 ok I will edit it

Comment: Side note, you can move the vector to the `create30div` function, to prevent copying the contents.   I.e. change the parameter `vector<int> vecNum` to `vector<int>&& vecNum` and `create30div(std::move(vecNum));`. Or you could just use a reference to there original vector in the function, but this will modify that vector: `vector<int>& vecNum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have off-by-one error in several places:
`vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i);`
should be
`vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i - 1);`

Another bug (in 2 places): `counter` never gets to `2`, because you `break;` the first time it is incremented. The 1st time you can fix the bug like this:

```
            int counter{0};

            for (int i = 0; i < vecNum.size(); i++)
            {
                if (vecNum.at(vecNum.size() - i - 1) % 3 == 2)
                {
                    vecNum.erase(vecNum.end() - i - 1);
                    counter++;
                    i--;
                    if (counter >= 2)
                        goto sum;
                }
            }

            return "-1";
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, as a side note, can you think of a better way other than `goto`  without writing a whole function?

Comment: "without writing a whole function" is the wrong criterion. More functions are better if they are short, clear, and allow avoiding repeated logic. I would extract *two* functions from your `create30div()`.